# Button not responding in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, tableview

I am using a .xib for my cell in a table view.  Inside the .xib, is another view (cellBackgroundView), and a button.  When I run the app, and click the button, it does not respond at all.  Instead, it calls the tableView's didSelectedRowAtIndexPath method which brings another view controller.

Using Xcode's Debug View Hierarchy, I discovered that I have a view overlaying the all the buttons (see pic attached: this overlaying view is highlighted).  This view (called backgroundView) that is overlaying my button is a View, within a view.  I have a feeling when you place a view in a view, and put a button in the initial view, the button isn't called because its below the view hierarchy.

How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to move background view to the back of the view heirarchy so that the buttons will be responsive?

Debug View hierarchy:
[image]

Structure of .xib
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two things that you could check

1) Do you have a delegate method for cell height and is the height returned correct? Unless you have `Clip Subviews` on for the `UITableViewCell`, the contents of the cell can be visible outside it's frame, but the parts that are outside the cell's frame are not registering user interactions.

2) Is some other view element higher in the hierarchy (lower in the XCode listing you posted) overlapping the button? iOS Simulators `Debug -> Color Blended Layers` can help spotting this.

**Edit:**
If I interpret the added screenshots correctly, you probably have the issue mentioned in the option 1) above. If the other elements showing in the screenshot are those listed as subviews of the `Cell Background View` they are mostly outside the parent view's frame and thus don't receive touch events. If the background view's frame is correct, then you might want to move the other elements as children for `Feed Cell` directly.

Also, the element listing suggests that you are using plain `UIView` as the parent element. I don't know the inner workings of your application, but if you only use this view in a `UITableViewCell` you might want to consider making the parent view a `Table View Cell` in the xib. This will reduce some bloat and allow you to configure some properties for the cell in the xib.

Comment: I actually have a view element higher in the hiearchy.  How do I push this view backwards?  This view is called backgroundView (see updated question).

Comment: @JoshO'Connor you can drag and drop the elements in the listing on your second screenshot. Note that the elements lower in the list are the ones having higher view index (`Profile Image View` has lower index than `Username Label`), and thus will be on top of any previous element. See my updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot assign your Button to code

Comment: No there is working code.  Ive created a simple view and it responds.  It isnt responding because its in a view, within a view (had to do that for autolayout)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Feed Cell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and `cellBackgroundView` is the property `contentView` of this cell.
If so, the cells property `backgroundView` should be behind your `cellBackgroundView` (the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/backgroundView) say: `UITableViewCell` adds the background view as a subview behind all other views and uses its current frame location.).
You could set the cells property `backgroundView = nil`, and see whether it is still there in the view hierarchy. If so, you do add a custom `backgroundView` on top of the other cells views somewhere.
To check this, you could read out the subview hierarchy of your cell in your method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with something like `NSArray *svs = cell.subviews;` (assuming `cell` is the `tableViewCell`) and set a breakpoint behind this statement.
`svs` usually contains first the `UITableViewCellContentView`, and above it the `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView`. The cells `backGroundView` will not be shown. You could check there your view hierarchy.
If by chance there is a custom `backgroundView` on top, you could - as a workaround, not a solution - bring the `contentView` to the front by sending to the cell `bringSubviewToFront:` with the `contentView` as argument. Then the button should respond.

Answer (score 0):

In your Structure of Xib Place your button below the view that is first the view is added to superView then the Button, then your button will work.

or you can code

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

[self.view insertSubview:yourButton aboveSubview:cellBackgroundView];

}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add an `UIButton` by code?
If so you should ensure you `addSubview:` into `cell.contentView` and not into `cell`.

Also you could try to apply `CellBackground` class to a view inside `contentView`, not directly to `contentView`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method.

```
[cell.contentView  bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

after that if you want to back in background then tou can use `sendSubviewToBack:` method .

After adding this methods your button is not responding set the `userIntractionEable` of button's superview.